# Find the number of times we can take log base two of this exponent

Tags: exponentiation

I'm not sure how to simplify this type of exponential expression. I would like to know $k$ many $log_{2}^{k}(n)$ such that $n \leq 1$
$$n = (2^{2^{2^{15}}})^2$$
So attempt I to simplify
$$n = 2^{(2^{2^{15}} ) + (2^{2^{15}})}$$
From here I'm not exactly sure how to simplify further
$$n = 2^{2^{4^{30}}}$$
So I figured I could bring the exponent of exponents down
$$n = 2^{16^{30}}$$
Turns out to be a very big number
$$n = 2^{1.329\times 10^{36}}$$

So $k = 2^{1.329\times 10^{36}}$?

Comment: $$ n = 2^{(2^{2^{15}} ) + (2^{2^{15}})} $$ is not $$ 2^{{2^{2^{30}}} } $$ but only $$ 2^{2^{(2^{15}) \ + \ 1} } \ \ . $$  (I put these on separate lines since this is verging on illegibility as it is...)

Comment: I think you have $2^{2^{2^{15}}} \approx 2^{1.4 \times 10^{9864}}$ and so its square is about  $2^{2.8 \times 10^{9864}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$n = (2^{2^{2^{15}}})^2=2^{(2^{2^{15}}+1)}$$  The $+1$ is negligible.  If you take one log, you have $$\log_2(n)=2^{2^{15}}\\\log_2(\log_2(n))=2^{15}\\$$  A third one gets you to $15$, then a little less than $4$, then a little less than $2$, then less than $1$.  So it takes six applications of the log function.